# Materialized view error in Postgres, when SELECTing a NULL FK?

Tags: postgresql, select, null, view

I have an error in Postgres where if I include certain fields in a query the query will return zero records.

I am using the PGAdmin client to connect to a vendor's database.  The table I am connecting to is, I believe, a materialized view of 1.6 million records, with a compound primary key (PK1 and PK2).

If I run this query:

```
select PK1, PK2
  from table  
  where PK1 = 123
```

I will get the appropriate subset, 100 records.

If I run either of these queries:

```
select PK1, PK2, FK1
  from table
  where PK1 = 123
```

or

```
select *
  from table
  where PK1 = 123
```

I will get zero records.  I think the FK1 field joins against a lookup table in this materialized view; and the error occurs when the FK1 value is NULL.

I'm not familiar with how materialized views are built in Postgres, but has anyone seen anything like this before?  Thanks.

Comment: what happens when you run `select PK1, PK2, coalesce(FK1,'')
  from table
  where PK1 = 123` ?..

Comment: Could you paste the script which is used to create the view and its constraints?

Comment: Vao Tsun - the FK is an INT, so when I use 'coalesce(FK1,-1)' no record is returned.  It's as though if the FK is mentioned anywhere in the Select statement - either directly, or in a function, or using '*', then no records will be returned.

Comment: Nuri Tasdemir - the underlying script that created this would be the property of the Vendor; I am just accessing the table via an ODBC connection.  So I don't know if this is a physical table, a dynamic view that acts like a physical table, or a materialzed view that acts like a physical table.

Comment: If you can connect with psql instead of pgadmin, you can say `\d+ the_table_name` to find out whether it's really a view, a materialized view, or a regular table, as well as the SQL used to generate it (if a view/matview). That might give you some clues.

Comment: The problem sounds a bit like this wild "virtual columns" feature, although I still can't reproduce the missing rows: http://bernardoamc.github.io/sql/2015/05/11/postgres-virtual-columns/

Comment: The vendor says that the materialzed view was created with INNER JOINS, and that explains why records are being dropped when the FK to the lookup table is NULL, and there is no corresponding record in the lookup table.  I am guessing the problem will go away if they change to LEFT OUTER JOINS.